# unable to slow down animation speed in ios

Tags: ios, core-animation, cabasicanimation, catransaction

I want to slow down animation speed when it is going to end.

I am going through this code.

```
[CATransaction begin];
CABasicAnimation *rotationAnimation;
rotationAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.z"];
rotationAnimation.byValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:20];
rotationAnimation.duration = 2;
rotationAnimation.timingFunction=[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn];
[CATransaction setCompletionBlock:^{
    imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(imageView.transform, DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(myAngle*32.72));
}];

[imageView.layer addAnimation:rotationAnimation forKey:@"rotationAnimation"];
[CATransaction commit];
```

But unable to slow down when it is going to end or in completion block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i mention in @rakeshbs 's comment I want to stop animation at specific angle so I modified this code by following.

```
[CATransaction begin];
CABasicAnimation *rotationAnimation;
rotationAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.z"];
rotationAnimation.byValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:20];
rotationAnimation.duration = 2;
rotationAnimation.fromValue = 0;
rotationAnimation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:SomeValue];
rotationAnimation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
rotationAnimation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
rotationAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
[ImageView.layer addAnimation:rotationAnimation forKey:@"rotationAnimation"];
[CATransaction commit];
```

by this code i'm able to stop at specific position via `fromValue` and controlling speed of starting and ending via  `[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];`

At the middle of animation if I want to increase the speed of animation I need to increase value of `rotationAnimation.byValue` and if decrease the speed I need to decrease value of same.

Here I would like to mention that via this method if i want to rotate MyImageView at once for 360 degree then I need to set `rotationAnimation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:6.25];`.

Comment: By modifying this code i don't need to CompletionBlock

Answer (score 1):

try using `kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseOut` instead of `kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn`

```
rotationAnimation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction
                                    functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseOut];
```

`kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn`
Specifies ease-in pacing. Ease-in pacing causes the animation to begin slowly, and then speed up as it progresses.

`kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseOut`
Specifies ease-out pacing. An ease-out pacing causes the animation to begin quickly, and then slow as it completes.

U can also change `rotationAnimation.duration` to slow down the animation completely.

```
 rotationAnimation.duration = 10
```

will make the animation run 10 seconds.
source : https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CAMediaTimingFunction_class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Predefined_Timing_Functions

You can also learn more about easing functions and how they behave from the following link.
http://easings.net

Comment: But it is not slowing down the CompletionBlock it just slowing down the rotationAnimation.

Comment: What do you mean slow down completion block? Can't you change the animation duration for slowing down the animation?

Comment: I've to stop animation on specific angle
So i'm using completion block. So the ending of animation is performed by completion block. I want to slow down it's speed only in completion block

Comment: so you want to rotate some angles at a constant speed, then slow down to an angle and stop at `myAngle*32.72` angle?

Comment: Yes,
By coding, I answered, I got the result how I want.